# What does Islam say about crossdressing?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, clothing

What does Islam say about crossdressing? I know that majority of the crossdressers aren't gay, and usually have normal families. They act feminine usually in privacy, and not in public, for fun. Is it haram if we buy these type of clothing from crossdressing shops online and do it in privacy? And no, I don't want to be one. I'm just asking about it.

Comment: Most do it as a hobby. Most have no desire to change genders. So is it still Haram?

Comment: To my knowledge, there is nothing in the Quran that prohibits or promotes that type of dress. Also, there is nothing that clearly defines what is male or female specific clothing.
The Quran does not define feminine or masculine behaviour either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> عن ابن عباس رضي الله عنهما قال: لعن رسول الله صلى الله عليه و سلم المتشبهين من الرجال بالنساء، والمتشبهات من النساء بالرجال. *صحيح البخاري.*
>
> Narrated by Ibn Abbas, may Allah be pleased with him: The Messenger of Allah, peace be upon him cursed from the men who imitate women, and from women who imitate men. *Sahih Bukhari.*

This is a crystal clear evidence that imitating women in anyway (including wearing their clothes) is prohibited even in private and in public as well, and those who do it are cursed by the Prophet PBUH.