Is crossdressing haram?
I've done a bit of research, I still can't quite understand, can a man dress like a woman in private?
one of the things I've found:
Narrated by Ibn Abbas, may Allah be pleased with him: The Messenger of Allah, peace be upon him cursed from the men who imitate women, and from women who imitate men. Sahih Bukhari.
If that is simply the answer, could someone explain it?

I have heard (citation needed) that it is haram for a man to wear woman's clothes. I cannot find a reference and don't know if it is also haram for a woman to wear men's clothes, and if this rule is strict, as, for example, in a theater play when everyone knows this is a man, not disguising his true nature. Usually @UmH will know a good reference.

See also https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/28285/55518 but I thought there was something about this in the Quran proper, not only in the hadith.
